# FluentValidation set validator on collection with Ruleset

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I'm creating a POST Rest API(ASP.NET Web API) to perform write operations,so have to validate data before inserting them into Database.I'm pretty new to using FluentValidation to validate the data. 
Suppose below are classes that I have and need to validate.

```
public class Listing
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    public List<ListingDetails> ListingDetails { get;set; }
}

public class ListingDetails 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public ListingStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum ListingStatus
{
    Active = 1,
    Converted = 2,
    LostToCompetitor = 3
}
```

Below code is responsible for validating the status based on the provided ruleset.

```
public class ListingStatusValidator : AbstractValidator<ListingDetails>
{
    public ListingStatusValidator() 
    {
        RuleSet("A", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x=>x.InquiryId).GreaterThan(0);
        });
        RuleSet("B", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Status).IsInEnum().NotEqual(ListingStatus.Active);
        });

        RuleSet("C", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Status).IsInEnum();
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the piece of code used to validatelisting.

```
public class ListingValidator : AbstractValidator<Listing>
{
    public ListingValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("common", () =>
        {
          When(x => x.ListingDetails != null && x.ListingDetails.Count <= 1000, () =>
            RuleForEach(x => x.ListingDetails).SetValidator(new ListingStatusValidator()));
        });

    }
}
```

Now to validate we will call validate method of the validator like below.

```
var validation = new ListingValidator().Validate(listing,ruleSet:"common");
```

Is it possible to pass ruleset when validating using setvalidator on collection of objects.Please see below snippet to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class ListingValidator : AbstractValidator<Listing>
{
    public ListingValidator()
    {
        When(x => x.ListingDetails != null && x.ListingDetails.Count <= 1000, () =>
            RuleForEach(x => x.ListingDetails).SetValidator(new ListingStatusValidator(),ruleset:"A,B,C"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute more then one RuleSet using *RulesetValidatorSelector*

```
var validation = new ListingValidator()
    .Validate(listing, new RulesetValidatorSelector("common", "A", "B", "C"));
```

In this case you don't need to specify RuleSets for *ListingStatusValidator*, RuleSets from *ListingValidator* will be passed to nested validator.